# Flask-admin + flask_mongoengine loading one select box value depends on the value of other select box

Tags: python, flask-admin, flask-mongoengine

I am using flask-admin + flask-mongoengine to create a admin panel for my website. I have a similar below models

```
class CarMake(db.Document):
    name = StringField()

class CarModel(db.Document):
    name = StringField()
    car_make = ReferenceField(CarMake)

class Car(db.Document):
    car_make = ReferenceField(CarMake)
    car_model = ReferenceField(CarModel)
```

I would like to get a admin page (create page for car) where the user selects Car Make (select box) and depends on the Car Make, Car Model select box should be loaded with models. I am googling for this problem. If anyone help me with relevant documentation or sample programs then advanced thanks.

Also I would like to know embedding the carModels document inside CarMake will be efficient or above design is good?